# ReactiveMongoTemplate .save not working on adding @compondindex annotation to the collection class

Tags: spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I have a Java class "Class A" whose object is being saved in a mongoDB using reactiveMongoTemplate.save operation in a reactive way.

```
public class A {
 // field 1
 // field 2
 ..
 // field n
}
```

This had been working perfectly fine and populated a lot of data to the corresponding collection.

Now I decided to introduce indexes to the collection, and hence added this annotation to the class

```
@CompoundIndex(name ="collection_index_name", def = "{'field1':1, 'field1':-1}", unique=true)
```

Now after adding this annotation, I see my mongoDB writer( a process which writes data to above mongodb collection ) getting stuck for long duration (15-20mins) or not processing anything further.
On debugging it, I see that the control reaches till the point I have `ReaciveMongoTemplate.save()` operation. But after the save reactive method is executed, I just get the below warning, and no writes happen to the collection.

```
Automatic index creation will be disabled by default as of Spring Data MongoDB 3.x.
    Please use 'MongoMappingContext#setAutoIndexCreation(boolean)' or override 'MongoConfigurationSupport#autoIndexCreation()' to be explicit.
    However, we recommend setting up indices manually in an application ready block. You may use index derivation there as well.

    > -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    > @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    > public void initIndicesAfterStartup() {
    >
    >     IndexOperations indexOps = mongoTemplate.indexOps(DomainType.class);
    >
    >     IndexResolver resolver = new MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver(mongoMappingContext);
    >     resolver.resolveIndexFor(DomainType.class).forEach(indexOps::ensureIndex);
    > }
    > -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As soon as I remove the above annotation or replace with a fresh new empty collection, and again run the same code, I see entries being saved immediately.

Is there any explanation for this behavior? Has this something to do with adding index to a collection, after a lot of data was already populated inside the collection?